# Play project compiles in IntelliJ IDEA but all imported Java classes are red (= not resolved)?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, java

I have a Scala (Play! in fact, if that matters) project which does compile well. However, all imported java classes are red, meaning IntelliJ can't resolve them. I tried a number of things: `sbt -> clean`; `sbt -> gen-idea`; `File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart`; - none of those helped me.

What might be the cause?

Comment: Can you describe how you've set up your project? That's the issue.

Comment: @wheaties, what do you mean by setting up?

Comment: how is your project set up in IntelliJ? What are your project settings? Where are you referencing imported libraries? Etc.

Comment: @wheaties isn't there only one way to do this? My projects settings and imported libraries are in my_app/project/MyBuild.scala.

Comment: don't confuse what you need for sbt with what you need for IntelliJ. They're two different products made by two different companies.

Comment: @wheaties, I don't do that on purpose.

Comment: Could you describe how you generate the play project and how IDEA knows about it (I assume you imported it -- so the question is what the steps were).

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, I was generated on my previous OS, it worked well there. On my current OS I just opened it because I just copy-pasted it from the previous OS (didn't import, just opened). I don't remember how I generated it exactly when I was creating it.

Comment: Ah, so it seems it's IDEA's fault not being able to resolve what it could find on another OS. Could you attach a screenshot of the errors in the question? What are the errors? Can you create a sample Java project and see what you end up with? I believe you'll need to set up IDEA to point at JRE/JDK as Rob says in his answer below.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, I've already told: the errors are "Cannot resolve the symbol" for each java symbol. The project has its sdk.

Comment: What are the symbols? Where's the file affected? Or files? Is the folder a source one?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, look at my update, these files are located everywhere in the project.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, as for sdk I have only `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` specified. Do I have to specify jre anywhere else?

Comment: I don't think so. JDK should be enough. You may want to ask about it on the IDEA's scala plugin mailing list at http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/idea/scala.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, it was ok previously, thus it may be fixed now, it's not a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "java classes", do you mean `java.` stuff? If so, it usually means you haven't told IntelliJ which JDK/SDK you're using. (**"File" | "Project Structure" | "Project Settings" | "Project" | "Project SDK"** to pick one, and **"File" | "Project Structure" | "Platform Settings" | "SDKs"** to add new ones to IntelliJ)